# Are there any consequences to calling clearInterval() on intervals that don't exist?

Tags: javascript

I'm checking the connection status of certain devices using javascript's `setInterval()` function that polls every 5 seconds. When those devices need to be removed or restarted for any reason I'll call `clearInterval()` to stop the interval before starting another when the device(s) are again restarted.

Sometimes the `clearInterval()` function will be called when there is no interval in the first place. For instance, we can disable the status check entirely so `setInterval()` never gets called. However, when the device is restarted `clearInterval()` - which exists in a different area of the codebase - still fires. Its argument will be either null or undefined.

My question is - are there any consequences to using `clearInterval()` in this way? Can you continue to call the function with a non-existent argument without adverse affects?

Comment: Nope. Calling `clearInterval` on something that may or may not actually be a current interval ID is a perfectly common practice. It makes code easier to manage.

Comment: `clearInterval()` `clearInterval(0)` and `clearInterval('foo')` all work just fine. That being said, clean code wins - don't rely on unintuitive behavior to make up for confusing code. The next dev is going to come along and spend a not insignificant amount of time trying to figure out what you were doing.

Comment: @Adam - agreed, cleaner code is better. In this particular instance though I think checking whether or not the interval exists before calling clearInterval() actually adds overall mental overhead. It also creates an additional area of the code that needs to be maintained should the logic change. Being able to just call clearInterval() with no adverse affects either way is really what I was hoping for and I'm glad that's the case!

Comment: @LaserWolf - you misunderstood. You shouldn't check whether it exists first, you should write the code in such a way that you don't need to call clearInterval unnecessarily. Right now you are calling clearInterval, "over here" when you are creating the interval, "over there", if you know what I mean. Those two things should be coupled a bit more tightly. You've spread the creation of the interval and the clearing of the interval too far apart.

Comment: @Adam - ah point taken.

Answer (score 2):

As @CertainPerformance already mentioned, in your case there is no harm.

But it was still interesting how much time those invocations take:

```js
const invocations = 1000000;
const d1 = new Date().getTime();
console.log(d1);
for (var i = 0; i < invocations; i++) {
  clearInterval();
}
const d2 = new Date().getTime();
console.log(d2);
console.log(invocations, 'invocations took', d2 - d1, 'millisecs');
```

Comment: Huh. That does kinda take a while comparatively. Luckily I'm nowhere near that quantity of invocations.